# Sum of a list without sum function

Tags: python

My professor asked the class to design a function to calculate the centered average of a list. I managed to complete the function alright, but I then saw that we were not allowed to use the *sum* function and have to have exactly one loop. Here is what I managed to do before getting stuck:

```py
def centered_average(lst: list) -> float:
    """
    Precondition: len(lst) >= 3

    >>>centered_average([1, 1, 5, 5, 10, 8, 7])
    5.2
    >>>centered_average([1, 2, 3, 4, 100])
    3.0
    >>>centered_average([-10, -4, -2, -4, -2, 0])
    -3.0
    """
    high = 0
    low = 0
    a = lst[0]
    b = lst[0]
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] > a:
            a = lst[i]
        high = a
        if lst[i] < b:
            b = lst[i]
        low = b
        elif
    total = sum(lst)
    return (total - high - low) / (len(lst) - 2)
```

Comment: What is "centered average"? Is it mean, median, or mode?

Comment: @Barmar centered average is average of numbers ignoring largest and smallest values

Comment: Are you allowed to use `sorted()`?

Comment: The centered average is the mean average of a list but you remove the largest and smallest numbers. If the largest or smallest number repeats it is only removed once.

Comment: I am not sure if I can use sorted()

Comment: You have an `elif` statement with no condition. Is that a copying error?

Comment: You can do, `list.remove(min(list))` and `list.remove(max(list))`, and then get the sum of the remaining elements, if you do not know exactly if `sorted` is allowed. Although, make sure that there is still an element in the list using `if list`.

Comment: @Sam no you can't. `min()` and `max()` are, themselves, loops. How could the code determine those values without each traversing the whole list? The requirement is a single loop, not 3

Answer (score 3):

You can remember the lowest and highest numbers which start as the first and last number of the list but can change.

Loop through all the numbers and if the number is higher or lower than high/low then set them. And add to a total.

After the loop you will have `i` which is the variable we used in the loop still in scope and that will be `N-1` (N being the count of numbers in the list)

So subtract the largest and smallest from total and divide by `i-1` which is the length minus 2

```
def centered_average(lst):
    high = lst[-1]
    low = lst[0]
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        n = lst[i]
        if n > high:
            high = n
        if n < low:
            low = n
        total += n
    return (total - high - low) / (i - 1)
    # and if that i part is confusing
    return (total - high - low) / (len(lst) - 2)
```

All of this in short form would be:

```
def centered_average(lst):
    return (sum(lst) - max(lst) - min(lst)) / (len(lst) - 2)
```

And if the precondition needs to be checked you may want to include a check for that at the beginning of the function:

```
if len(lst) < 3:
    raise ValueError("lst length must be greater than 3")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try in this way.

```
def centered_average(lst: list) -> float:
    """
    Precondition: len(lst) >= 3
    
    >>>centered_average([1, 1, 5, 5, 10, 8, 7])
    5.2
    >>>centered_average([1, 2, 3, 4, 100])
    3.0
    >>>centered_average([-10, -4, -2, -4, -2, 0])
    -3.0
    """
   
    
    high = lst[0]
    tot = 0
    low = lst[0]
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] > high:
            high = lst[i]
        if lst[i] < low:
            low = lst[i]
        tot += lst[i]
    return (tot - high- low) / (len(lst) - 2)
print(centered_average([1, 1, 5, 5, 10, 8, 7])) #5.2
```

The loop calculates `high`  as the highest value and `low` as the lowest value and `tot` as the total value. Then subtract `high` and `low` from total divided by length of array -2.

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what the OP did wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: yeah will do that

Comment: Thank you! It works when you substitute "high" and "low" in the return statement for "a" and "b".

Comment: I'm sorry to bother again but can you explain what is happening with the tot variable?

Comment: We are just adding all the values to `tot` variable. It's substitute for `sum` function

Answer (score 0):

Putting @Sam answers in code, something like the below should satisfy your requirements

```py
def centered_average(lst: list) -> float:
    """
    Precondition: len(lst) >= 3

    >>>centered_average([1, 1, 5, 5, 10, 8, 7])
    5.2
    >>>centered_average([1, 2, 3, 4, 100])
    3.0
    >>>centered_average([-10, -4, -2, -4, -2, 0])
    -3.0
    """
    lst.remove(max(lst))
    lst.remove(min(lst))
    total = 0
    for i in lst:
        total += i
    return total / len(lst)

print(f"First test: {centered_average([1, 1, 5, 5, 10, 8, 7])}")
print(f"Second test: {centered_average([1, 2, 3, 4, 100])}")
print(f"Third case: {centered_average([-10, -4, -2, -4, -2, 0])}")
```

Output:

```py
First test: 5.2
Second test: 3.0
Third case: -3.0
```

Comment: What if OP cannot use `min` and `max` functions? If they can't use `sum` I'd assume they can't use them.

Comment: `min()`, `max()` and `.remove()` all have loops under the hood.

Comment: I already explained in response to Sam in the comments that they are loops